# How to speed up Google App Engine Go unit tests?

Tags: performance, unit-testing, google-app-engine, optimization, go

I am currently writing a lot of unit tests for my package that runs on GAE Go. The package in question is focused on data saving and loading to and from appengine/datastore. As such, I have about 20 unit test files that look a bit like this:

```
package Data

import (
    "appengine"
    "appengine/aetest"
    . "gopkg.in/check.v1"
    "testing"
)

func TestUsers(t *testing.T) { TestingT(t) }

type UsersSuite struct{}

var _ = Suite(&UsersSuite{})

const UserID string = "UserID"


func (s *UsersSuite) TestSaveLoad(cc *C) {
    c, err := aetest.NewContext(nil)
    cc.Assert(err, IsNil)
    defer c.Close()
    ...
```

As a result, each individual test file appears to be starting its own version of devappserver:

[image]

Repeat this 20 times and my unit tests run for over 10 minutes.

I am wondering, how can I speed up the execution of my testing suite? Should I have just one file that creates aetest.NewContext and passes that onwards, or is it due to me using separate Suites for each unit test? How can I speed this thing up?

Comment: Can you copy some more of the log especially the sections taking up most of the time? I don't use GAE, so you should try debugging this yourself, but there seems to be several places where a 15 second timeout wait kicks in https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/aetest/instance.go#156

Comment: @EmilDavtyan Most of the logs look like the log attached. It's just a lot of those logs. I am guessing each function that creates Context also calls for the Context to be closed, so that might be what's slowing it down...

Comment: Why are you effectively testing another package?

Comment: @freeformz I'm not testing another package, but testing a package that uses appengine packages.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom `TestMain` function:

```
var ctx aetest.Context

var c aetest.Context

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    var err error
    ctx, err = aetest.NewContext(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    code := m.Run() // this runs the tests
    ctx.Close()
    os.Exit(code)
}

func TestUsers(t *testing.T) {
    // use ctx here
}
```

This way the dev server is started once for all the tests. More details on `TestMain` are available here: http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main.

Comment: Thanks! This increased my test speed by about a million percent.